# Accessing an item from a key value pair object derived from a parent relationship

Tags: php, laravel, object, eloquent, relationship

I am trying to implement a created_by column in my users' table.

I created a migration file to add the new column to the users' table:

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedInteger('created_by')->default(0);
        });
    }
```

I have a User model which has the following relationships:

```
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
    }

    public function createdBy()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(self::class, 'created_by');
    }
```

In the UsersController, I have this method:

```
    public function view($id)
    {
        $user = User::with(['roles', 'createdBy'])->where('created_by', Auth::id())->find($id);
        return $user;
    }
```

When I return the user variable, I get this result:

[image]

Now, I want to access the value from "email" in "created_by". I tried to do this:

```
return $user->created_by
```

What I'm getting is 2 but what I want to get is "**biodunna@mailnator.com**".

I also tried `return $user->created_by->email` but it returned an error since the result I'm getting from `return $user->created_by` is just a number.

I want to fetch the email value "**biodunna@mailnator.com**".

Comment: It seems the laravel is confused coz of it gets 2 cerated_by objects.
Could you please change the `createdBy` relationship function name with `createdByUser` and then try to access with `$user->createdByUser->email`.

Comment: @MiteshRathod
Thanks, it works fine now.

Comment: Cheers mate! @banjoko, will you accept/vote my answer, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change the `createdBy` relationship function with the `createdByUser`.

here we just change the function name to avoid conflict between column name and relationship name.

```
public function createdByUser()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(self::class, 'created_by');
}
```

so now, you can access like

```
$user->createdByUser->email
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your JSON response this should work:

```
$user[0]->created_by->email
```